# Authenticate at Google Cloud Storage JSON API with Firebase ID token

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I have a mobile app (Android/iOS) that uses the Firebase SDK for several Firebase services (including Authentication and Storage).

Now there's a subsystem within the app that can't directly access the Firebase SDK, but I need to upload files to Storage from this subsystem. HTTP(S) requests are possible, so I tried to use the [Storage JSON API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/) for uploading.

However, an OAuth 2.0 token is required for authorizing requests via the JSON API. Is there a simple way to receive such a token, when there's already a signed-in user in the Firebase SDK? It seems the only thing I get from the Firebase SDK is the "Firebase ID token" (JWT token), but I don't know how to convert it (or if this is even possible) to an accepted OAuth token for the JSON API.

Comment: Why can't this subsystem use the Storage SDK? This seems weird since it seems to have access to the Auth SDK.

Comment: @Doug Stevenson: It doesn't have access to the Auth SDK either. I'd like to pass the token as a simple string parameter to the subsystem.

Comment: Still, my question is why can't this subsystem use the Storage SDK?

Comment: It's actually a third-party plugin that I can't (or don't want to) modify. Technically, it might be possible, but I was wondering if it could also work with the JSON API.

Comment: Sorry to revive an old question, but I have the same situation. My client side code is in python, so I use the firebase REST API to log the user in and get the JWT. But then I can't seem to use that JWT to upload files to storage. There is no front-end python client library for firebase storage.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to do the petition from the plugin itself and it might not have the permissions.

Did you [pass it to sign In With Custom Token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth#authenticate-with-firebase) to the SDK when your users sing-in?
I read that after that, a Custom Token and credentials are attached to the user's profile.

Why don't you try to do the petition from the user's profile instead of doing it from the plugin?